# Деление дробных чисел

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть `class Money`

oop.h

```
#pragma once
class Money
{
private:
    unsigned long long rubles;
    unsigned int penny;
public:
    Money();
    Money(const Money& money);
    Money(unsigned long long r, unsigned char p);
    Money operator /(Money &rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Money &data);
};
```

oop.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "oop.h"

Money::Money()
{
    rubles = 0;
    penny = 0;
}
Money::Money(const Money& money)
{
    rubles = money.rubles;
    penny = money.penny;
}

Money::Money(unsigned long long rubles, unsigned char penny)
    :rubles(rubles), penny(penny) {}
Money Money::operator /(Money &rhs)
{
    return Money(rubles / rhs.rubles, penny / rhs.penny);
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const Money& data)
{
    os << data.rubles << "," << data.penny;
    return os;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "oop.h"

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    Money rubles(10,1);
    Money rubles2(5, 8);
    std::cout << rubles / rubles2 << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Как правильно поделить две дробные числа, где целая и дробная часть - это две разные поля?

Comment: Не проще хранить одно `unsigned long long` число - число копеек?

Answer (score 2):

Программа, классы и т.п. - это всего лишь модели реальности.

```
Money Money::operator /(Money &rhs)
```

Скажите, если вы поделите 15 рублей 25 копеек на 3 рубля 47 копеек, то какую **сумму** (а у вас операция деления возвращает именно `Money`) вы получите?

В лучшем случае вам нужно возвращать значение типа `double`:

```
double Money::operator /(Money &rhs)
{
    return double(rubles*100+penny)/(rhs.rubles*100+rhs.penny);
}
```

Comment: Как преобразовать `Money` в `double`?

Comment: Зачем? Вы не поняли, что я написал в ответе?